# What is the name of this kind of chart/graph?

Tags: single-word-requests, mathematics

The chart that shows the value of every aspect of an entity. It represent properties of an entity visually, with areas so that we can easily regconize the strong/weakness, etc...

Here is an example:

[image: A 5-axes chart called "Dire Team", with axes called "Push Power", "Tank", "Damage", "Disable", "Support". The values plotted on each axis are 25, 20, 5, 5, 20 respectively. The points are joined to display a blue, irregular pentagon. The chart is pentagonal in shape, made up of 5 concentric, light grey, regular pentagons, each pentagon has a value, a multiple of 5, from 0 to 25, 0 being in the middle, 25 being at the edge.]

What is the name of this kind of chart/graph?

Comment: Why do people more frequently than I would prefer, ask questions which they should ask at the Maths forum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with "radar chart". I list some options below.

- Radar Chart: https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/including-charts-and-graphics-pentaho-reports-part-2, http://www.arcplan.com/en/blog/tag/chart-types/, http://isu.ifmo.ru/docs/bip_1013/bip.1013/e10416/biptempbld.htm, http://www.theinformationlab.co.uk/2013/08/05/radar-charts-in-tableau/
- Polar Chart: http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/dbprogramming/report-builder-3-0-chart-1/
- Radial Plot: http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/jQuery/2012.2/CLR4.0/html/igDataChart_Series_Types.html#_Ref321842472

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_chart) also gives these options: web chart, spider chart, star chart, star plot, cobweb chart, irregular polygon, kiviat diagram.

Comment: Also ***spider chart***.

Comment: And even [**spider web chart**](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=spider%20web%20chart)

Comment: Thank you very much! I needed the keyword to do my research. That helps a lot :)